How to filter on key column in ksqldb?
I have a source table that looks like this:
+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|ROWTIME                                                     |id                                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|1718204168745                                               |"2337"                                                      |
|1718101864313                                               |"1337"                                                      |
|1718265930643                                               |"3337"                                                      |
|1718204113848                                               |2337                                                        |
|1718204231979                                               |"2337"                                                      |
|1718263392544                                               |3337                                                        |

The id column is the primary key.
I try to query the data and filter on the id
SELECT RowTime, `id` FROM `Data` WHERE `id` = '"2337"';
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|ROWTIME                                         |id                                              |
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|1718204231979                                   |"2337"                                          |
Query terminated

SELECT RowTime, `id` FROM `Data` WHERE `id` = '"1337"';
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|ROWTIME                                         |id                                              |
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
Query terminated

SELECT RowTime, `id` FROM `Data` WHERE `id` = '"3337"';
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|ROWTIME                                         |id                                              |
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|1718265930643                                   |"3337"                                          |
Query terminated

SELECT RowTime, `id` FROM `Data` WHERE `id` = '2337';
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|ROWTIME                                         |id                                              |
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
Query terminated

SELECT RowTime, `id` FROM `Data` WHERE `id` = '"2337"';
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|ROWTIME                                         |id                                              |
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|1718204231979                                   |"2337"                                          |
Query terminated
```sql
SELECT RowTime, `id` FROM `Data` WHERE `id` = '3337';
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|ROWTIME                                         |id                                              |
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
Query terminated

When I export the messages from the topic using confluent cloud I see this



I have produced some messages using the confluent cloud UI and some using confluent-cli
confluent kafka topic produce dev-streaming --parse-key --key-format string
Starting Kafka Producer. Use Ctrl-C to exit.
3337:{"id":"3337"}

Why do I have the same key in different partitions and why can't I filter on some of the ids?
It looks like I can filter on the ids hat I entered using the UI but not the ones i entered using confluent-cli.
